# How to test GET/POST or better way?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest, intel-xdk

I am writing an app that will send POST/GET requests from a remote client to a server.  As a way to test and also educate myself I was trying to make these requests by writing a simple html file that resides on my desktop with a form that would POST to a server side php file.  I also tried using ajax style requests or XMLHttprequests independent of and connected to a form but I received an error in the console:

```
Cross Origin Request Blocked
```

For all attempts form or no form.  I have read that this is because I am making the request from `FILE://` and this is not allowed by browsers unless CORS is enabled in some way.  I have also read that using a webserver to host the file might fix the problem but I don't understand what is meant by webserver (separate or same domain? lamp, xammp, mamp?) and I am not interested in overriding security (allowing cors with headers) if I am eventually going to have to find a secure way when it goes live anyway.

As I said I am really just trying to test and I would like my html files to communicate with the server-side php from another machine instead of just putting all files together in the same domain/folder.  Is there a way to do this using html/javascript or Websockets or anything html5 has to offer that might be useful?

code examples are welcome but if anyone could help me grasp this concept better it would be greatly appreciated.  I am a noob XD

I am open to a better approach entirely if one exists, the only constraint I have is that everything on the UI/Client end is going to be written in html/javascript but I can utilize either or both intel XDK api and Cordova api as well.

Please help and thank you.

Comment: localhost alone might not help, but you can navigate to the remote site in chrome/ff, and test your code in the javascript console. that way of testing is free, simple, and 100% effective.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send some HTTP requests to test the server-side of your app I would strongly recommend you use an HTTP client like Fiddler:

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Also, read this:

[GUI HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435838/gui-http-client)

A desktop-based client will have a nice GUI with plenty of features to tweak, save, send, resend your requests.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use pythons `SimpleHTTPServer` to serve the html file. Then when you go to your browser and go to `127.0.0.1:8000` the origin will be the same.

You can run the server by going into the directory that has the html file and running the command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. This will serve the content of that directory on port 8000 and it should allow the requests to be made without a CORS exception.

Heres the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: is this different in anyway from testing with mamp(localhost)?

Comment: It is a little bit different. Mamp has a lot more capabilities, like being able to use php and mysql. If you dont need any php code then this would work the same way as mamp. All SimpleHttpServer does is serve static content(html, css, javascript) on localhost on a given port

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you disable the same-origin policy in your browser in order to test cross domain AJAX request from a local file.

For example, with Google Chrome on Windows you can disable this by launching chrome with the following command :

C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security

Together, both of these flags will allow you to test cross-domain ajax requests from a local file. These flags are relevant across Mac, Windows and Linux.

Comment: Is this safe to do outside of localhost? like if I were to try xhr send request from file://examplexhr.html to http://www.somedomain.com/somephp.php?

Comment: You should be able to send a request without being blocked by a Cross Origin Requests (CORs) message in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is not on how to write the requests but you can bypass writing those if you are using the latest version of  the Intel XDK. If you go to the services tab in the latest version of the Intel XDK, there is a service by the name of Sandbox Explorer. It has a GET and POST method UI. Just plug in the URL and you will see the response immediately. You can use this to debug the server that you are writing. Once you have the server returning the right response, create a data binding to use the GET API in your client side javascript or html code. Cross origin is taken care of.